# Nginx. How get whence there is a request

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-redirect

I want make redirects, according to whence there is a GET-request.
For example if my image used on domain1.com - then return 404 error, else ok.
Please any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear, but it seems you are trying to prevent hot linking when other website tends to load images from your web site without permission. [The docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#example) shows an example:

```
valid_referers none blocked server_names
               *.example.com example.* www.example.org/galleries/
               ~\.google\.;

if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
}
```